# AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'rout'

Tags: python, heroku

When using heroku I attempted to start my app, but it crashed shortly after. I typed in

```
heroku logs
```

and it gave me an error

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'rout'
```

Any help?

Here is some more of the error code

```
2013-12-18T01:35:42.281842+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2013-12-18T01:35:42.282303+00:00 app[web.1]:     @app.rout('/')
2013-12-18T01:35:42.282303+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'rout'
2013-12-18T01:35:42.292705+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-18 01:35:42 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2013-12-18T01:35:42.281842+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
2013-12-18T01:35:42.492900+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-18 01:35:42 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-12-18T01:35:42.492900+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-18 01:35:42 [2] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2013-12-18T01:35:43.735731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2013-12-18T01:35:43.722240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2013-12-18T01:35:48.270010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=boiling-journey-3522.herokuapp.com fwd="24.6.156.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Looks like a typo. Is that supposed to say `route`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a typo I believe. It should have been

```
@app.route('/')
```

Comment: Wow... for every single line of code I put 'rout'. Thanks for catching that